# How to use Python multiprocessing Pool.map to fill numpy array in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I want to fill a 2D-numpy array within a for loop and fasten the calculation by using multiprocessing.

```
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Pool


array_2D = numpy.zeros((20,10))
pool = Pool(processes = 4)

def fill_array(start_val):
    return range(start_val,start_val+10)

list_start_vals = range(40,60)
for line in xrange(20):
    array_2D[line,:] = pool.map(fill_array,list_start_vals)
pool.close()

print array_2D
```

The effect of executing it is that Python runs 4 subprocesses and occupies 4 CPU cores BUT the execution doesn´t finish and the array is not printed. If I try to write the array to the disk, nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Do you recall how you ran this code?  In commandline, jupyter or a script?

Answer (score 5):

The following works. First it is a good idea to protect the main part of your code inside a main block in order to avoid weird side effects. The result of `pool.map()` is a list containing the evaluations for each value in the iterator `list_start_vals`, such that you don't have to create `array_2D` before.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fill_array(start_val):
    return list(range(start_val, start_val+10))

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    list_start_vals = range(40, 60)
    array_2D = np.array(pool.map(fill_array, list_start_vals))
    pool.close() # ATTENTION HERE
    print array_2D
```

perhaps you will have trouble using `pool.close()`, from the comments of @hpaulj you can just remove this line in case you have problems...

Comment: With larger arrays, I get an error `Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('cannot join current thread',) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored`.  `apply_async` does not give this warning.

Comment: Without the `pool.close()` command, I don't get this `Error`.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the feedback... I tried producing an array which is `10000 X 10000` with no problem, changing 60 by 10040 and 10 by 10000...

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of machine size and speed.  Mine's relatively old.

Comment: On further testing it appears that a `pool.join()` is more important if the mapping is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the array fill, you can use `pool.apply_async` instead of `pool.map`.  Working from Saullo's answer:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fill_array(start_val):
    return range(start_val, start_val+10)

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    list_start_vals = range(40, 60)
    array_2D = np.zeros((20,10))
    for line, val in enumerate(list_start_vals):
        result = pool.apply_async(fill_array, [val])
        array_2D[line,:] = result.get()
    pool.close()
    print array_2D
```

This runs a bit slower than the `map`.  But it does not produce a runtime error like my test of the map version: `Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('cannot join current thread',) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to running the `pool.map` in for loop , The result of the map() method is functionally equivalent to the built-in map(), except that individual tasks are run  parallel.
so in your case the pool.map(fill_array,list_start_vals) will be called 20 times and start running parallel for each iteration of for loop , Below code should work

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fill_array(start_val):
    return range(start_val,start_val+10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array_2D = numpy.zeros((20,10))
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)    
    list_start_vals = range(40,60)

    # running the pool.map in a for loop is wrong
    #for line in xrange(20):
    #    array_2D[line,:] = pool.map(fill_array,list_start_vals)

    # get the result of pool.map (list of values returned by fill_array)
    # in a pool_result list 
    pool_result = pool.map(fill_array,list_start_vals)

    # the pool is processing its inputs in parallel, close() and join() 
    #can be used to synchronize the main process 
    #with the task processes to ensure proper cleanup.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Now assign the pool_result to your numpy
    for line,result in enumerate(pool_result):
        array_2D[line,:] = result

    print array_2D
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunalely the effect is the same. Python starts subprocesses and occupies the PC but nothing happens. I´m running the code on an Windows 7 machine (dual core CPU with hyperthreading => virtually a quadcore), Python 2.7.5 32bit and I use SpyderLib as programming interface.

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE i ran the code i posted  in windows environment and it seems to be working , I think you are running the code with out the if "__main__"==__name__: , if that's the case the code will run indefinitely in windows , please refer to the Stack Overflow link regarding the importance of if condition in windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main

Comment: I just tried to run the sample code above including "if __name__ == "__main__": " but nothing happens. I don´t know whats wrong here..