# Multiprocessing example giving AttributeError on Mac

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing

Recently I reinstalled the latest Anaconda3 on Mac and found some an error in

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
    return x*x

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.apply(f, [1])
```

The error is like

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

But the same code worked several days before!!!

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: your specific error is from trying to run multiprocessing code in an interactive mode using "spawn" as the startmethod (the new standard method for MacOS). you will run into new errors also without `if __name__ == "__main__":` as well due to the change. Many questions here related to Windows specifically now apply to MacOS as well (windows only has "spawn" whereas Mac and Linux also have "fork". Mac used to use "fork" by default, and linux still does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python for MacOS changed the default ["start method"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) in Python 3.8. This means you will now need to protect your code from execution on `import` by placing all multiprocessing code (and anything else that should only run in the parent process) inside a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. You will also run into issues with interactive interpreters like jupyter, or IPython because there isn't always a "main" file to import. It is sometimes possible to configure your IDE to get around this somehow, but the most compatible solution is to run your code from a system terminal. Alternatively you could [manually switch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) back to using "fork" which is faster and uses less memory in some instances, but can fall victim to deadlock when using certain threaded modules (like `logging`).

Comment: I tried `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it did not work. So do I have to write functions into a file and then import them? I don't think this is reasonable.

Comment: Oh, it works with other non-interactive interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.apply(f, [1])
```

Comment: Could you please explain why adding a test fixed the issue ?

Comment: This issue has been referred to many times in Stackoverflow. Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main

Comment: Thank you but this does not work on Mac. I read some similar pages before but all of them are about Windows

Comment: It works with other non-interactive interpreters. Thank you.

Comment: I developed and ran this code on macOS. Make sure you run it from a command line as some IDEs seem to have issues with this