# Avoid multiprocessing.Pool to run Globals

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sys

I am currently working in Python. I need to work with multiprocessing.Pool and set the current working directory as the **file** dir an then adding the parent directory to sys.path. The problem is that, when multiprocessing.Pool starts, it runs again the line `sys.path.insert(0,'..')` which I want to avoid. Is there any way to make multiprocessing.Pool not running the Globals or anything which is outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` snippet of code?

```
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing

os.chdir(sys.path[0])
sys.path.insert(0,'..')
print(os.getcwd())

def Worker(j):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        p.map(Worker, range(10))
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Comment: that is what `if __name__ == "__main__":` is for, you put code that is supposed to run only in the parent process under the `if`

Comment: @ZLi Of course, indeed that is what I was expecting. But, at least for my example, is not the case.

Comment: This sounds like it could be an XY problem -- why do you need to add different things to your path? Could you instead just open the files directly without modifying path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way multiprocessing works is that when it hits the `p.map(Worker, range(10))` line, it would start a new child process, and run **the whole script** again from line 1 (new child process would import the calling module). The lines under the `if` would not run again in child process. To avoid the `sys.path.insert(0,'..')` to be repeated in the child process, you need to put that line under the `if`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main) for more details.

```
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing


def Worker(j):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir(sys.path[0])
    sys.path.insert(0,'..')
    print(os.getcwd())

    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as p:
        p.map(Worker, range(10))
        p.close()
        p.join()
```