# Why is executor.map from multiprocessing running the entire main again?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following snippet below from a main.py script

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

a bunch of code above with that has a write-to-disk process that was meant to be only run once
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

context =  get_context('spawn')
someInitData1= context.Value('i', -1)
someInitData2= context.Value('i', 0)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4,
                                        mp_context=context,
                                        initializer=util.init_func, 
                                        initargs=(someInitData1,someInitData2)
                                       ) as executor:
        multiProcessResults= [x for x in executor.map(util.multi_process_job, 
                                           someArguments1,
                                           someArguments2,
                                          )]
```

I intend only to have `util.multi_process_job` be parallelized with multiprocessing. Although, for some reason, with this snippet, all of the code in my main.py get's repeated from the beginning and in parallel as a new process by the workers.

What is strange to me is that the following snippet works fine for my needs when I run it via jupyter notebook. Only the specified function runs. The problem only occurs when I convert the ipnyb file to .py file and run it as a regular python script on a linux machine.

Comment: Because each process has to import your module (with some multiprocessing backends; the `fork()`-based ones don't have this issue). While it's _possible_ to avoid this by changing how you configure `multiprocessing`, the _better_ answer is the one that also makes your code compatible with a wider array of static analysis tools: You shouldn't have your main code unconditionally at the top level; put it a function, call that function only if `__name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: Not closing this as a duplicate because some of the details of that question are Windows-specific and don't apply to you in entirety, but [Python multiprocessing on Windows, `if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main) is _very_ relevant (on Windows, `fork()` isn't an option as it is on Linux, so the configuration that avoids the issue without fixing your code isn't possible... but you should still fix your code anyhow).

Comment: This problem seems to pop up fairly regularly.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! 
To quickly test my script, I wrapped all the codes of my main.py in the suggested if condition.
Surely enough, the script is working now.
I am interested in what you said with 
"While it's possible to avoid this by changing how you configure multiprocessing"
Do you have any references for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
context = get_context('spawn')
```

...wherein you're forcing a mode that's compatible with Windows, but creates each new process as a completely new copy of Python. Consequently, those new processes need to `import` your module separately; thus they rerun any code that's invoked on import.

To avoid this, use `get_context('fork')` to make each new process be a copy of your existing Python process, with all the prior state (like the modules already loaded and cached in memory) available.

---

Alternately, you can put all your top-level code inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` gate, so it only runs when your script is *executed*, but not when it's *imported*.